# saving activity state on close of the app by back key press

Tags: android

I am creating an App. It has 4 count-down timers. 
   My problem is,
         In the middle of the count-down timer running user may press the back key and close the App. **I want to let the countdown-timer run it's count so that the user can see the updated version of it when he opens the App on next time.** 
        I thought to manage the state using onSaveInstanceState Callback but I read in the document that it been not called on the event of back key press of the activity. And I tried to check...yes it is not. Is any chance I can solve this using services?

Can someone shed some light on this please.

Note: I am using Handler.postDelayed for running count-down timers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch the event when the user presses the back key, there's a method on the Activity class you can override, I believe it's onBackKeyPressed